# Android Gradle issues

Tags: android, gradle

**Hi everyone, i just open my android studio and got these issues, tried research and not finding a way to get rid of this, kindly help me.**

### *The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore. Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning. It will be removed at the end of 2018.. Failed to resolve: ch.acra:acra:4.9.0 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: com.adeel:easyFTP:1.0 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2 Open File Show in Project Structure dialog Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12 Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog*

**here is my gradle file**

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        /*jcenter()
        google()*/
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**and this is app level gradle**

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.t4s.apl_test"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 16
        versionName "1.6.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}
configurations.all {
    // Check for updates every build
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    // Volley (HTTP library)
    // Crash Reports Library (ACRA)
    implementation('ch.acra:acra:4.9.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json'
    }
    // Volley (HTTP library)
    // Volley (HTTP library)
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.3.0'
    //compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.3.0'
    implementation 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    // compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Image Picker
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.7.5'
    implementation 'com.adeel:easyFTP:1.0'
    implementation files('libs/simpleftp.jar')
    implementation group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient' , version: '4.4.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last find a solution.

Just added these two lines

```
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
```

in App level gradel 
and in gradle.properties

```
android.enableAapt2 = false
```

Answer (score 0):

In gradle.properties file located in the project root folder, try replacing the following line

```
android.enableAapt2 = false
```

with

```
android.enableAapt2 = true
```

Hope this helps.